# C# ASP.NET Foreign Characters(ü) Ampersand Confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a simple website and I need to use Turkish characters (ç,ş,ğ,ı,ü) in usernames and other fields. When executing the following statement,

```
Response.Redirect("View2.aspx?ApplicantName=" + applicantname);
```

It cannot get the applicant's name when the applicant name contains "ü". I suspect it is because "ü" has ampersand (&) in its representation which is `&#252;`.

So what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

**All you need is the proper URLEncoding**

```
Response.Redirect("View2.aspx?ApplicantName=" + Server.UrlEncode(applicantname));
```

Or, if you are using Unicode:

```
Response.Redirect("View2.aspx?ApplicantName=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(applicantname, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
```

Don't forget to [URLDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sacf9e4b.aspx) on the other end.

**References**

- [MSDN for Server.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)
- [MSDN for HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text, Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h10z5byc.aspx)
- [MSDN for System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)

Comment: For the first solution, it gave this error "A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client". And where to add the second one ?

Comment: I'm not experienced unicode, but by the looks of your input, I'd say you probably need to utilize the HttpUtility method and specify the Unicode encoding format.

Comment: Well I am not sure how to do that. I added<globalization uiCulture="tr-TR" culture="tr-TR" fileEncoding="iso-8859-9" requestEncoding="iso-8859-9" responseEncoding="iso-8859-9"></globalization> to web.config but other than that, I don't know where to add your solutions

Comment: For the second, it gives The name 'Encoding' does not exist in the current context

Comment: "System.Text.Encoding is not a namespace"

Comment: I tried again and it still gives the same error "not a namespace" :/

Comment: All I can do at this time is suggest looking at the code samples in the MSDN link for system.text.encoding. If you do not have access to that namespace, I think that is a separate issue and is outside the scope of the question (in other words, it's beyond me)

Answer (score 2):

Add this line (or change if it exist) to your web.config file's system.web section.

```
  <globalization culture="tr-TR" uiCulture="tr-TR" fileEncoding="iso-8859-9" requestEncoding="iso-8859-9" responseEncoding="iso-8859-9" />
```

Comment: The exact one exists in my web.config but it doesn't solve the problem.